Sign Excel documents with Trusted Signing?
With the looming expiration of our last PFX code-signing certificate, we have moved to Azure Trusted Signing. All our conventional binaries are now signed this way, and the sole holdouts are our Excel documents.
I have been researching using Trusted Signing for Excel documents, but cannot find any examples or guidance.
Is it possible to sign Excel documents with Azure Trusted Signing?
